# Linear function does not work properly in d3.js. Cant see what is the problem

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

```
const colorScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([
  d3.min(data.features.map(d => d.gdp.unGDP)), 
  d3.max(data.features.map(d => d.gdp))
])
  .range(["#92D1A4", "#743742"]);
```

For example, if I test colorScale(10), I am getting rgb(0,0,0)

Comment: If `d.GDP.unGDP` is a number, `d.gdp` is definitely not a number

Comment: As @BallpointBen pointed, if `d.gdp.unGDP` is a numeric value, `d.gdp` is an object, and cannot be interpreted as a number